# Gstreamer with Jackd causing audio issues

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, jack, gstreamer

I have a gstreamer pipeline set up to route the audio to jackaudiosink. I'm using jackd to route audio to multiple devices. It's pretty good in that there's no latency in the audio. But the sound quality seems to suffer. The audio crackles & pops very often and I can't seem to figure out what I should do to avoid it. Is there something in jackd that I can setup for this? It doesn't seem to come from anything else in the pipeline because I tried recording the audio right before sending it to jackaudiosink and it sounds fine up to that point.

I did try replacing the jackd server for pulseaudio to see if there would be a difference and it looks like the quality is better but the problem does not go away completely. For this solution all I did was change the jackaudiosink to pulsesink and have the pulseaudio server running. Even here the recording right before this sink is fine.

I'm very new to audio hardware, linux and everything else I'm using so if reading specific docs will help please do suggest some.